# Verificar checkbox com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho um checkbox que ao ser marcado ou desmarcado executa uma update no banco, com ajax. 
Porém não sei como analisar o evento de mudança de estado dele.
Se uso o `checked` ele considera só o estado atual do botão.

Alguem pode me ajudar ? Segue minha função (chamo ela no onchange do checkbox):

```
function check_cadmanual(id){
    var id_pronto = id.split("_");
    var codveiculo = id_pronto[1];
    event.preventDefault();
    if(document.frmveic.iptcadastromanual.checked) {
        document.frmveic.funcao.value = "ativo";
    } else {
        document.frmveic.funcao.value = "inativo";
    }
    startloader();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
        url: "/configuracao_veiculo",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            timeout:default_timeout,
            iptcadastromanual:codveiculo,
            funcao: document.frmveic.funcao.value

        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        stoploader();
        ajaxget('veiculo', 'Veículos');
        if(document.frmveic.funcao.value == "ativo") {
            mensagemSucesso("Esse veículo já pode ser acessado no cadastro manual de clientes !");
        } else {
            mensagemValidacao("Atenção","Esse veículo não está mais disponível no cadastro manual de clientes !");
        }
    });
}
```

A montagem do checkbox:

```
$sql = "select codveiculo, nome, indcadastromanual from veiculo 
            where codempresa=".$codempresa." order by nome";
$rst = my_query($connR, $sql);
foreach($rst as &$row){
    if($row['indcadastromanual'] == 1) {
        $checked = "checked='checked'";
    } elseif ($row['indcadastromanual'] == 0) {
        $checked = " ";
    }
    $htmlveiculo='<ul>';
    $htmlveiculo .="<input type='checkbox' name='iptcadastromanual' class='onoffswitch-checkbox' id='iptcadastromanual_".$row['codveiculo']."' onchange='javascript:check_cadmanual(this.id);' ".$checked." >"
    $htmlveiculo .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: O que é o `id`? Podes mostrar como isso está no HTML?

Comment: Oi @Sergio, coloquei o html na pergunta.

Comment: Ok, juntei mais detalhes à minha resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca um evento `change` no seu checkbox, e verifique se esta checado ou nao com o comando `$('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')`

```
  //Exemplo
  $('#myCheck').bind('change',function(){
    alert('Checkbox checado?'+ $(this).is(':checked'));
    //Seu ajax aqui
  })
```

Veja se ajuda.

Comment: o `is(':checked'))` fez exatamente o que eu precisava, nem precisei alterar mais coisas.. Super obrigada !!!

Answer (score 5):

Sugiro correres essa função pelo JavaScript e não inline pelo HTML.

Dessa maneira tens acesso ao elemento que foi clicado e facilmente lês o estado com `this.checked`.

Exemplo:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', check_cadmanual)
function check_cadmanual() {
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = this.checked ? 'marcado' : 'desmarcado';
}
```

```html
Clica aqui -> <input type="checkbox">
<div id="res"></div>
```

#### jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a8dpwg5w/

#### actualização:

Com o HTML que juntaste agora à pergunta sugiro então, usares o código assim:

```
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').on('change', check_cadmanual);

function check_cadmanual() {
    var id = this.id;
    var checked = this.checked
    // e o resto igual, e para saberes o estado tens agora uma variavel com essa informação
```

retirando esse `onchange` do HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Supondo que você tenha o seguinte `checkbox`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkVeiculo" value="" />
```

Você pode atribuir um evento onclick via javascript:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkVeiculo" value="" onclick="javascript:check_cadmanual(this)"/>
```

Na sua função `check_cadmanual`:

```
function check_cadmanual(elemento) {
    var checkbox = $(elemento);
    var checked = checkbox.prop("checked");
    if (checked) {
      // seu ajax.
    } else {
      // TODO
    }    
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela dica !

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria algo assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idDoCheckbox" data-id="idDoVeiculo" />

$(function() {
    $("#idDoCheckBox").click(function() {
        startLoader();
        var checked = this.checked;
        var funcao = checked ? "ativo" : "inativo";
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

        // suas chamadas ajax...
    });
});
```

Tente não misturar muito jQuery com puro JavaScript. Não há nenhum problema nisso, mas se já está implementando jQuery, use de todos os recursos deles para facilitar sua vida e acelerar seu desenvolvimento.

Comment: Obrigada pela dica !